# How do I create an even curved top?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I am trying to model this heart shape compact mirror (example one). First, I used a “Bezier Curve” to create the shape. Then I converted the curve to a mesh, and then extruded it. The problem now is I don’t know how to create and even arc on the top like this (example two). I have tried using “Grid Fill” in edit mode and then highlighting a face in the middle and moving it up using the “Proportional Editing Sphere”, but the arc comes out wonky because the edge flow is all over the place (example three.) Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve an even arc over my heart shape? Thanks in advance! [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead create this kind of concentric topoloy:

[image]

Then pull up the loop edges like that:

[image]